# Webpack4 npm start Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

I npm start Vue project is ok,but I open the browser page blank.It's Uncaught following error,

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Console view is as below,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:768)
    at fn (app.js:142)
    at Module../src/main.js (app.js:10476)[enter image description here][1]
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:768)
    at fn (app.js:142)
    at Object.0 (app.js:10547)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:768)
    at checkDeferredModules (app.js:44)
    at app.js:844
    at app.js:847
```

when I degugger I find there have error:

> modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports,
>   hotCreateRequire(moduleId));

```
// The require function
    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {

        // Check if module is in cache
        if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
        }
        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
            i: moduleId,
            l: false,
            exports: {},
            hot: hotCreateModule(moduleId),
            parents: (hotCurrentParentsTemp = hotCurrentParents, hotCurrentParents = [], hotCurrentParentsTemp),
            children: []
        };

        // Execute the module function
        **modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));**

        // Flag the module as loaded
        module.l = true;

        // Return the exports of the module
        return module.exports;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have up to date versions of npm and webpack?

Comment: @Josef7   I have Version: webpack@4.10.0 and vue@2.6.10

Answer (score 1):

Clear the browser catch memory and do hard refresh.

Please refer [this](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/959)